# Authenticate Active Directory users without asking username and password

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there any way that we can authenticate Active Directory user automatically without username and password say by getting his PC name (RF18-PC\RS-Vivekh).

Here is what i am trying to achieve. I have an application where users can login by entering his details. I want to implement other type of login through Active Directory where initially i will configure my AD and will add some users within my LAN giving a name and will store the info in database and then the user login to the system with that username and password and can go to our web page and my app will automatically detects by getting the PC-NAME and will look into the database  and detects whether there is corresponding user in the db with that name then i will automatically get the User details and pass it to `PrincipalContext` to verify whether he exists in AD. if he exists then he will go to the home page directly. Is this achievable

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you can use the security option to use windows authentication to automatically check the user that is logged in. You will also have to change the settings to use NTLM over Negotiate.

Is this what you ment?

Comment: I dont completely understand the edit. If you mean that you want to check if the user is logged in at a domain computer and if the user has acces to get to the home page the security option for windows authentication is just what you need. Else i don't fully understand your edit.

Comment: okay lemme try to be more clear. Suppose i have around 10 systems and a server connected within a LAN. I have configured configured AD in server and created individual accounts for all the 10 PC's. Say system1,system2,.....system10 so now the i hosted my application in server and i will try access the app from one of the 10 systems. Say i'm accessing the app from system2 (where i have logged into the system with given credentials for AD say domainname/system2) the app needs to validate whether system2 is in the AD that we have created if yes it should be redirected to home page directly

Comment: What's stopping me is i am unable to get the PC user name which is system2 and domain name in the above case. I am able to get that by Environment.UserName and Environment.UserDomainName in local system but when i host it into the server i am getting the username of the server itself all the time regardless of from where i'm accessing the App. So i am getting RSS-SERVER/SERVER rather than RF-PC18/system2

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want to do your authorisation check on computers instead of users?

Comment: Is it possibel to achieve this using AD or do we have any entirely different alternative

Comment: I'm still looking for you but didn't find anything we could use yet :(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62249/discussion-between-vivekh-and-dave).

Comment: How is your problem going? Have you already found out a solution?

Comment: No Dave still struggling with the same